# Regularity of the dependence of the flow on the vector field definining it

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, differential-equations, banach-spaces, sg.symplectic-geometry, banach-manifold

Let $M$ be a smooth compact manifold and $k \geqslant 1$.
Define $\mathfrak{X}^k(M,TM)$ to be the set of vector fields $M \rightarrow TM$ of class $C^k$. As $M$ is compact, endowing $\mathfrak{X}^k(M,TM)$ with the norm $|| \cdot ||_{\mathcal{C}^k}$ makes it into a Banach space.

Define now $\phi^1 : \mathfrak{X}^k(M,TM) \rightarrow \mathcal{C}^k(M,M)$ to be the map sending a vector field $\mathbb{X} \in \mathfrak{X}^k(M,TM)$ to its time 1 flow $\phi^1_\mathbb{X} \in \mathcal{C}^k(M,M)$. The manifold $M$ being compact, the space $\mathcal{C}^k(M,M)$ endowed with the norm $|| \cdot ||_{\mathcal{C}^k}$ can be given the structure of a smooth Banach manifold (see for instance Moore, Introduction to global analysis).

The map $\phi^1 : \mathfrak{X}^k(M,TM) \rightarrow \mathcal{C}^k(M,M)$ is thus a map between smooth Banach manifolds. My question is the following :
***What is the regularity of this map between smooth Banach manifolds ? Is it smooth, $C^k$, $C^{k-1}$ for instance ?***

In particular any reference on the matter would be much appreciated.

Comment: This is essentially the question about (uniform) smoothness with respect to the function on the right-hand side of a differential equation, isn't it? So the answer is $C^k$. Just consider the usual proof of differentiability with respect to a parameter from an infinite-dimensional space.